# not running problem

Tags: errors

Hello everyone I am trying to run this. I made some changes since this is a template. The image shows the error:
[image]

This is the part where the problem seems to be:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath} %uso de equaciones
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} %para introducir imagenes
\usepackage{enumerate} %para enumerar 
\usepackage{makeidx} %para hacer el index 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{apacite} %para hacer apa bibliografia
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{rotating} %para rotar la hoja y tabla 
\usepackage{booktabs} %hacer tablas 
\usepackage{adjustbox} %ajustar tabla a hoja
\usepackage{breqn}  %ajustar ecuacion cuando se sale del margen
\usepackage{slashbox,multirow} %para varios textos en la linea de cabeza de las tablas
\usepackage{chngcntr} %para contar pie de pagina seguidas
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%para las paginas fancy
\usepackage{epsfig} %para las graficas en eps
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}%\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\textheight22.5cm \topmargin0cm \textwidth16.5cm
\oddsidemargin0.5cm \evensidemargin-0.5cm%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\; #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\; #1{}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\thispagestyle{fancy}%
\addtolength{\headwidth}{0cm}
\unitlength1mm %Define la unidad LE para Figura
\marginparwidth0cm
\parindent0cm %Define la distancia de la primera linea de un parrafo a la margen
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\let\PBS=\PreserveBackslash
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
%Neuer Befehl f\"{u}r die Tabelle Eigenschaften der Aktivkohlen
\newcommand{\arr}[1]{\raisebox{1.5ex}[0cm][0cm]{#1}}
%Neue Kommandos
\usepackage{Befehle}
%Trennungsliste
\hyphenation {Reaktor-ab-me-ssun-gen Gas-zu-sa-mmen-set-zung
Raum-gesch-win-dig-keit Durch-fluss Stick-stoff-gemisch
Ad-sorp-tions-tem-pe-ra-tur Klein-schmidt
Kohlen-stoff-Mole-kular-siebe Py-rolysat-aus-beu-te
Trans-port-vor-gan-ge}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = blue,
        urlcolor  = blue,
        citecolor = blue,
        anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref} %para referencias tipo link
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

If anyone can find the error I would appreciate it.

Many thanks..

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable. Which template do you use? Please name it.

Comment: this is the link where the template is: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/plantilla-tesis-maestria-y-doctorado-universidad-nacional-de-colombia/bvkytfhxsskk#.WdphI2iCy1s

Comment: I'm sorry to have to break the news to you, but this template is simply dreadful. No good. Whatsoever. Is somebody forcing you to try to use it? If not, stay away from it. *Run away* from it. If somebody is indeed forcing you to use it, please *beg* that person to back off. And if he/she won't back off, just ignore that person and find some other template anyway. It really is that bad. A separate concern: the link you provide in the preceding comment appears to point to a different template, *not* to the one you posted in the body of your query. What's going on?

Comment: do you really use _all_ those packages in a single document? certainly you should not be loading `epsfig` and probably not `epic` or `eepic` and should not be specifiying `dvips` to `graphicx`, and probably should not be using `ansinew` input encoding.

Comment: Wow that is really bad news for me since I accomplished about 90% of the work using this template. As I said during the time I have been using it I managed to make changes that fits my work (costumize). And I really need to find the problem because to migrate to other template I don't know how easy it could be!!

Comment: OK @DavidCarlisle I will delet those. Many thanks

Comment: @Mico It is not the exact template since I've been working on it for some time and I made changes that fit my own work.

Comment: What was the point in providing a link to a file which is not the template you're working with?

Comment: @Mico because with this template I started. I am sorry if I am not being very clear. All I could ask if for help in this matter.

Comment: It seems that a braket (or boht) { } is (are) missing but I can't see where it could be?

Comment: You're missing a closing curly brace at the end of `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\; #1{}}`.

Comment: Just added the closing curly brace but not I have more errors!

Comment: Of course you have more errors!! It's a dreadful template, after all. But why aren't you listing the errors up front?

Comment: @WilmerRojas don't just delete the packages I mentioned: delete _all_ the packages that you are not using.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-exhaustive list of major defects in the template:

- The directive

  ```
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\; #1{}}
  ```

  is missing a closing curly brace, `}`.
- One should *not* use the `fancyhdr` package with the `scrbook` document class. Indeed, your log file should contain the following warning:

  ```
  Class scrbook Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
  (scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
  (scrbook)              I'd suggest to use 
  (scrbook)              package `scrlayer' or `scrlayer-scrpage', because
  (scrbook)              they support KOMA-Script classes.
  (scrbook)              With `fancyhdr' several features of class `scrbook'
  (scrbook)              like options `headsepline', `footsepline' or command
  (scrbook)              `\MakeMarkcase' and the commands `\setkomafont' and
  (scrbook)              `\addtokomafont' for the page style elements need
  (scrbook)              explicite user intervention to work.
  (scrbook)              Nevertheless, using requested
  (scrbook)              package `fancyhdr' on input line 22.
  ```
- Two separate and mutually incompatible citation management packages -- `apacite` and `natbib` -- are loaded.
- Are you really, truly using the `ansinew` input encoding? If your editor software is reasonably modern, it's probably using the `utf8` input encoding.
- Why is the option `dvips` passed to the `graphicx` package?
- Since the `graphicx` package is loaded, there can be no justification for loading the `epsfig` package. There's probably no point in loading `epic` and `eepic` either.
- The instruction `\addtolength{\headwidth}{0cm}` seems to be utterly pointless.
- Learn how to use the `geometry` package. It's grossly inefficient to modify low-level parameters such as `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` directly.
- Instead of modifying the low-level parameter `\baselinestretch` (see `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}`), one should load the `setspace` package and issue the instruction `\setstretch{1.1}`.
- Does one really need to load both `lscape` and `rotating`? Use either one package or the other, *but not both*.
- The package `slashbox` is deprecated; in fact, it's no longer part of the `TeXlive` distribution. Do look into using the `diagbox` package. If you don't know what the `diagbox` package (or, for that matter, the `slashbox` package) does, there's probably no reason for loading it in the first place.
- The package `here` does nothing but load the `float` package. Indeed, the entire contents of `here.sty` consist of the following few lines:

  ```
  % (Public domain.)
  %
  % The original here.sty by David Carlisle was withdrawn many years ago.
  % The [H] modifier is now implemented in float.sty, which this here.sty
  % simply reads.  Another option is to use a float specifier [!ht], which
  % usually has the same effect, and keeps floats in the right order.  The
  % present trivial here.sty merely allows old documents to keep running.
  %
  % --Karl Berry, November 2009.
  \RequirePackage{float}
  ```

  For the sake of code hygiene, you shouldn't be loading `here` at all. If you must, do load the `float` package directly.
- The package `Befehle` appears to be non-standard; for sure, it's not part of TeXLive. By the way, do you really need to provide those hyphenation exceptions for several German-language words?
- The package `xcolor` should be loaded -- if at all -- before, not after, `hyperref`. And, since all hyperlink colors are set to `blue`, provide a single option -- `allcolors=blue` -- instead of setting `linkcolor`, `urlcolor`, etc separately.

I could go on, and on, and on, and... I trust you get the point, though.

Comment: yes i got the point. I shall use a better and simpler template. The pain is that as I said I accomplished 90% of my work. So it is like starting a little bit... However many thanks for your effort I really apperciate it.